# SOAP Header for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap

I have a problem with adding header info to a SOAP Message. Anyone having an idea about how to do this in a correct way?

I am succesfully able to add Authenticator part but still not able to add UserName and Password inside Authenticator as showed below. You can see the C# code below as well!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <soap:Header> 
    <Authenticator xmlns="http://www.namespacename.com/services/"> 
      <UserName>string</UserName> 
      <Password>string</Password> 
    </Authenticator> 
  </soap:Header> 
  <soap:Body> 
    <ListItems xmlns="http://www.namespacename.com/services/"> 
      <strCode>string</strCode> 
    </ListItems> 
  </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

C# Code

```
var client = new MySoapClient();
client.GetListCompleted += (a, b) =>
{
    var list = b.Result;
};

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Authenticator", "http://......./", credentials);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
    client.GetListAsync(App.CouponCampaignCode);
}

public class _ServiceCredential
{
    [XmlAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.None)]
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Password;
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [XmlAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.None)]
    public string UserName;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error message?

Comment: I actually got a custom reply from the server saying that the data I send is not correct, but the username and passward are actually there (checked with fiddler)

Comment: Using Fiddler I have been able to modify the SOAP message manually to find out exactly what in the SOAP that is not corrct.

Comment: Using fiddler I could figure out exactly what in the SOAP messageis not correct.     <Authenticator xmlns="http://www.namespacename.com/services/">  
      <UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestApp.App">myUserName</UserName>  
      <Password xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestApp.App">myPassword</Password>  
    </Authenticator>

Comment: Fiddler is great for tracking down such issues. So I assume you know what the problem is now?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void callWebservice()
{
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, Password, domain);
    HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(url, credentials);
    XDocument soapEnvelope = CreateSoapEnvelope(soapEnvelope );
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelope, request);
}

private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, NetworkCredential credentials)
   {
        string action = link;// my action link
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Credentials = credentials;
        req.Headers["SOAPAction"] = action;
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";
        return req;
    }

private static XDocument CreateSoapEnvelope(string content)
{
    XDocument soapEnvelopeXml = XDocument.Parse(content);
    return soapEnvelopeXml;
}

private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XDocument soapEnvelopeXml,                          HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream((IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) =>
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(postStream);
        postStream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }, webRequest);
}
```